# Sending SOAP request with child elements in ksoap2

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

I am not even sure if that is what it is called what I want to do but I need to send something to the server  that looks like this

```
<ECMMAID>int</ECMMAID>
  <appIncData>
    <int_inc_num>int</int_inc_num>
    <respTime>dateTime</respTime>
    <arriveTime>dateTime</arriveTime>
    <sceneControlledTime>dateTime</sceneControlledTime>
    <retStationTime>dateTime</retStationTime>
    <sceneClearedTime>dateTime</sceneClearedTime>
    <assist>boolean</assist>
    <unitNotes>string</unitNotes>
    <incidentPath>string</incidentPath>
    <totalCalculatedFromThePathMiles>double</totalCalculatedFromThePathMiles>
    <startOdmeterMilage>double</startOdmeterMilage>
    <endOdmeterMilage>double</endOdmeterMilage>
    <startEngineHours>double</startEngineHours>
    <startPumpHoursReading>double</startPumpHoursReading>
    <engineHours>double</engineHours>
    <currentPumpHoursReading>double</currentPumpHoursReading>
  </appIncData>
```

Now every other web service I have done with `ksoap` has always been just a bunch of properties with values but nothing where you have a property children under the tag

basically just like this

```
request.addProperty("ECMMAID","");
request.addProperty("Name",);
request.addProperty("Content",);
request.addProperty("STID",);
request.addProperty("IncNum",);
request.addProperty("Notes","");
request.addProperty("uploader",);
```

How do I send something like I need to in ksoap or should I just use `HttpPost?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something similar to the code below. I used a similar code in my app to send xml format data to server.

```
 PropertyInfo req = new PropertyInfo();
        req.name="appIncData";// may be different in your case  
        req.type=String.class;
        req.setValue("<ECMMAID>"+int+"</ECMMAID>"+
                     "<appIncData>"+
                    "<int_inc_num>"+int+"</int_inc_num>"+
                    " <respTime>"+dateTime+"</respTime>"+
        "</appIncData>");

        request.addProperty(req);
```

Comment: so basically its going to be the same thing as doing it as an `HttpPost` request just without all the headers and such...thats unfortunate

Comment: for that you need to have mechanism that can be handled on the client side and on the server side.